# How can i pass the multiple values to the single parameter in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
def(df:DataFrame):DataFrame = {
  val emptyDf = Seq.empty[(Long,String)].toDF()
  val p1 = "('2005-01-01')"
  val p2 = "('2005-12-31')"
  val query = sqlContext.sql(s""" select * from ${emp} where ${dt} between ${p1} and ${p2} """)
  for((i,j)<-k) {
    some operation
  }
  emptyDf
}
```

This logic is working but I want to pass the parameters `p1` and `p2` till 2018 for each and every iteration. Here I need 14 iterations every iteration need to replace the next year value. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing whole range you can simply use **year()** function to just compare year. [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions)

```
def(df:DataFrame):DataFrame = {
    val emptyDf = Seq.empty[(Long,String)].toDF()
    val p = "'2005'"
    val query = sqlContext.sql(s""" select * from ${emp} where year(${dt}) = ${p} """)
    for((i,j)<-k) {
        some operation
    }
    emptyDf
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build an array of tuple with possible combinations of p1 and p2 and iterate over the array to build your query and execute for each element in the array.

Something like

```
val dateRanges : Array[(String,String)]= Array(("2005-01-01","2005-12-31"), 
                                               ("2006-01-01","2006-12-31"))
dateRanges.foreach(//execute your method here)
```

Array can be built manually or you can use date functions to add/subtract months/years from a date.